Before Print and After Print Event error is not working
Before Print and After Print Event error is not working.
sheet2 has certain coloured cell. (before and after print)
but when print out, coloured cell should be blank.
MY Code
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

Sheets(2).Range("B4:H17").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Sheets(2).Range("B23:H25").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
'free to add more ranges

Application.OnTime Now, "AfterPrint"
'Return back to original color

End Sub

Sub AfterPrint()


Sheets(2).Range("B4:H17").Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)    "No colour"
Sheets(2).Range("B23:H25").Interior.Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)

End Sub


All of the BeforePrint code will run before it prints and I think Application.OnTime Now will run immediately.  You should use something like Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:15") to wait 15 seconds, but pretty sure it will wait 15 seconds, run the AfterPrint code and then print.

Hmmm, might have been wrong in my previous comment.  This link might help:  https://excelribbon.tips.net/T013624_Executing_a_Macro_After_Printing_is_Done.html
